# Typing multiple MUI themes via module augmentation

Tags: typescript, material-ui

I want to setup two directories in one repository (with one `package.json` and `tsconfig.json`) which both will use MUI and TypeScript. Each of these directories will use its own theme (so one `ThemeProvider` in each root). In the main `index.tsx` file in the root directory, I want to decide which branch will be rendered. So we have a setup like this:

```
// A/index.tsx
declare module '@mui/material/styles' {
  interface BreakpointOverrides {
    xs: false
    sm: false
    md: false
    lg: false
    xl: false
    mobile: true
  }
}

const a = createTheme({
  breakpoints: {
    values: {
      mobile: 300,
    },
  },
})

const A = () => (
  <ThemeProvider theme={a}>
    <Box sx={{ width: ({ breakpoints }) => breakpoints.mobile }} />
  </ThemeProvider>
)

// B/index.tsx
declare module '@mui/material/styles' {
  interface BreakpointOverrides {
    xs: false
    sm: false
    md: false
    lg: false
    xl: false
    desktop: true
  }
}

const b = createTheme({
  breakpoints: {
    values: {
      desktop: 1200,
    },
  },
})

const B = () => (
  <ThemeProvider theme={b}>
    <Box sx={{ width: ({ breakpoints }) => breakpoints.desktop }} />
  </ThemeProvider>
)

// index.tsx
render(true ? <A /> : <B />, document.body)
```

My problem is, that when I try to customize the themes, the module augmentation of `a` (as described in the MUI documentation) will also set the typings for the theme of `b` (which should define it's own customizations).

The question here is: is it possible to tell TypeScript that it should use the augmentation in `A/index.tsx` only for the `A` directory and the one for `b` only for `B`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible. To achieve a setup like that you have to use multiple `tsconfig.json`, so the types to not infer with each other.

Answer (score 0):

You can capture manually all the module augmentation into two different .d.ts files and load it manually into the client package.